# MYSQL: repeating table1 content times content in table2

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables of which `table1` includes usernames and `table2` includes dates that user `x` did something.

```
 table1:               table2:        

|----------|          |-------|----------|
| username |          | User  | date     |
|----------|          |-------|----------|
| user1    |          | user1 | 1.1.2013 |
| user2    |          | user2 | 2.4.2013 |
| user3    |          |-------|----------|
|----------|
```

Now i want to get a list that shows all the users from `table1` times the amount of rows on `table2` and also shows if the date applies to all or 2 or only one user.

```
|-------|----------|
| User1 | 1.1.2013 |
| user2 | -        |
| user3 | -        |
| user1 | -        |
| user2 | 2.3.2013 |
| user3 | -        |
|-------|----------|
```

So basically i just want to when reading lines from table2, that did other users do something on this same date.

If you have any ideas how this could be done, please help me out :)

---

Next thing i need to add, is months :) And it should be so that the list has months by year for e.g.

```
| MM/YYYY |  user  | Kg  |
|---------|--------|-----|
| 01/2013 | user1  |  0  |
| 01/2013 | user2  |  0  |
| 01/2013 | user3  |  5  |
| 02/2013 | user1  |  2  |
| 02/2013 | user2  |  4  |
| 02/2013 | user3  |  7  |
|   ...   | ...    | ... |
| 12/2013 | user1  |  0  |
| 12/2013 | user2  |  1  |
| 12/2013 | user3  |  0  |
|---------|--------|-----|
```

I think that for this table i need some kind of if statements in the latest updated query.
And i don't mind if have a solution to share since i think i'm unable to solve this quite soon :)

So i need to check, did someone get fish in january, if no => mark 0
If you got several fish, mark average or sum to that month to the user that got several fish. So same idea as earlier but this allows nicer line chart "segments" since all measure points are at the same vertical line.

Comment: User date is a single column?

Comment: Oh sorry, i'm lame using this forum (new to this) but no, they are separate columns, user and date are separate.

I was able to acheive something with
select user, date from table1 join table2 but then i need still some logic to only show the dates on the user it realy matches on. Now it seems that the output puts dates on all users...

Comment: It seems to me you don't need table 1,since all the data is in table2. Clarify.

Comment: Ok. Users are catching fishes with weight x. I want to draw a line chart of average weight and that's why i need this. And i want all the "measurement" points happen on same date points.
I have a "work-around" on this in php but there it is hardcoded for couple of users (4 users) and i don't like that kind of workaround.

Comment: I just want to get as much out of mySQL as possible before tossing values to PHP code to draw the line-chart.

I also want the line-chart to react on empty fishing days making an other linechart showing "how good fishmen" we are using a style of manchester encoding to draw the "fish/nofish" chart.

I hope you could come up with a nice solution. I of course also will try to figure it out and i will answer here if i can make it work.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fe34 A fiddle if somebody needs it,I`ll get back to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked this task. don't think that this is the optimal solution, but it works well:

```
SELECT un, tmp 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT  t1.username as un, 
            t2.user as u, 
            t2.date as d, 
            t2.date as tmp
        FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2 
        WHERE t1.username = t2.user
        UNION
        SELECT  
            t1.username as un, 
            t2.user as u, 
            t2.date as d, 
            '-' as tmp
        FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2 
        WHERE t1.username <> t2.user
    ) AS res
    ORDER BY d ASC
) AS tot_res
```

updated:

```
SELECT un, tmp 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT  t1.username as un, 
            t2.user as u, 
            t2.date as d, 
            t2.date as tmp
        FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2 
        WHERE t1.username = t2.user
        UNION
        SELECT  
            t1.username as un, 
            t2.user as u, 
            t2.date as d, 
            '-' as tmp
        FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2 
        WHERE t1.username <> t2.user    
    ) AS res
    GROUP BY res.un, res.d
    ORDER BY d ASC
) AS tot_res
```

Comment: LIKE A GLOVE!!!
Thank you Nik. I'll just have to understand the whole query so that i can use with more columns. I was able to add also the fish weight column with same scheme. Can you sjust explain what this means:

WHERE t1.username <> t2.user  <= the <> operator ?

Comment: There is still one problem in the query. It does multiply the number of times the names are written in the output if more than 1 user has got a fish on same date. So if only one user has got a fish on 1.1.2013 the query ouputs correctly. But if 2 users got a fish on the same day, the number of results are multiplied by 2 and so on.

Comment: the output will be something similar to:

|user   |   date    |
|-------|-----------|
|user1  |  1.1.2013 |
|user2  |  1.1.2013 |
|user3  |  -        |
|user1  |  -        |
|user2  |  -        |
|user3  |  -        |

Comment: updated. was hard to see without enough of sample data. `t1.username <> t2.user` means "not equal"...

Comment: Wau! Increadible. I'm still having problems understanding the query but i must study! Thank you for you effor. The updated query does now what i was looking for... NICE!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username,date FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.username=t2.user GROUP BY date ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but this result does not do it. Let me explain. I want the output to also show the usernames with empty date columns so that the usernames in table t1 are rolling as many times there is results on the other table (t2), as shown in my example output in the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username, date FROM table1 t1 
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.username = t2.user
```

Comment: This did basically the same as the query above this, not match yet.
The closest i have gotten is with:
SELECT username,date FROM table2 t2 
JOIN table1 t1
ORDER BY date ASC

Answer (score 0):

```
|-------|----------|
| User1 | 1.1.2013 |
| user2 | -        |
| user3 | -        |<-- we need some way of distinguishing between this row...
| user1 | -        |
| user2 | 2.3.2013 |
| user3 | -        |<-- and this row
|-------|----------|
```

so

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
              , y.date
              , CASE WHEN z.date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END catch 
           FROM table1 x 
           JOIN table2 y 
           LEFT 
           JOIN table2 z 
             ON z.user = x.username 
            AND z.date = y.date
          ORDER
             BY x.username
              , y.date;
```

sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81494/6

(and, obviously, for this to work properly dates need to be stored using a date data type)

Comment: Something is not right in this query since there are more results of catched fish on some dates.

Comment: check this, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81494/1
The same issue as one post earlier. I 2 users got fish on a same date, the results will be multiplied by 2.

Comment: yes, you query does the same :) This was very short and nice query! Thank you